# Fetch Elements of parent Tag Selenium Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

```
<div class="cell column-1 name data-id-c13181" data-id="c13181" data-field="name">
    <a class="name" title="Scan">Scan</a>
</div>
```

I am searching for element with Title matching "Scan" using

```
drivername.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@title = 'Scan']")
```

How do I fetch data-id value for use.

Comment: drivername.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@title = 'Scan']").text

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps mentioned below for fetching any attribute of the parent tag.

**Java Code Snippet**

```
String dataID= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Scan']/parent::div")).getAttribute("data-id");
System.out.println(dataID);
```

**Python Code Snippet**

```
dataID= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Scan']/parent::div").get_attribute("data-id")
print(dataID)
```